# how can i take out the first two rows of each subject ID

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data that looks like below. I want to subset the data by taking the first two rows of each subject ID and discard the rest. How can I do that for all individuals?

```
ID TIME CONC
1   0    1
1   5    5
1   7    11
2   0    0.5
2   1    10
2   2    15
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df %>%
     group_by(ID)%>% 
     slice(1:2)

 #   ID TIME CONC
 #1  1    0  1.0
 #2  1    5  5.0
 #3  2    0  0.5
 #4  2    1 10.0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:2], by=ID]
#   ID TIME CONC
#1:  1    0  1.0
#2:  1    5  5.0
#3:  2    0  0.5
#4:  2    1 10.0
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[1:2], by=ID]$V1,]
```

Or using `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=seq_along) <3),] #from @John's comments
```

In this case, you could shorten the above code to (considering that `ID` is not a `factor` variable.

```
df[with(df, ave(ID, ID, FUN=seq_along) <3),]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TIME = c(0L, 5L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 2L), CONC = c(1, 5, 11, 0.5, 10, 15)), .Names = c("ID", 
"TIME", "CONC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you. That is perfect ! Looks like the dplyr is a handy package :)

Comment: @Amer No problem.  Yes, the recent version of `dplyr/tidyr` have added some new functions.

Comment: The base R is unnecessarily complicated. You could use the `with` but why the extra `seq_along`? And the `%in%` is probably slower than simpler logic? How about `df[ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN=seq_along) < 3,]`?

Comment: @John I was considering cases where `ID` column is `factor`. Try `df$ID <- factor(df$ID); with(df, ave(ID, ID, FUN=seq_along))`  Thanks for the comment and `<3`, it would be a bit more compact.

Comment: You'd just select any other column that's not a factor for the first argument to `ave` if ID was a factor.

Comment: @John Yes, I could have used `CONC` column but the OP didn't give a dput output.  So, for general purpose, I used that code.